# How to show alert or any message using liquid in Dynamic 365 portals?

Tags: dynamics-crm, liquid, portal, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-portals

I want to display an alert message or output using the liquid in the Dynamic 365 portal,
Any command to show a message in the output using the portal liquid ??

Comment: Did you verify my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this liquid syntax to display alert message:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger">{{ resx['Access_Denied_No_Permissions_To_View_These_Records_Message'] | h }}</div>
```